# AccessでSQLServerにリンクテーブルで接続したい。

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Microsoft AccessをSQLServerにリンクテーブルで接続しようとしています。Accessで「外部データ」→「新しいデータソース」→...と進んみ「データソースのテスト」が完了して「ファイルデータソース」をOKしたところで「テーブルのリンク」表示されました。そこでテーブルの一覧から何を選択すればよいかわからなくなりました。

Microsoftのサポートのサイトを見ても「リンクまたはインポートする各テーブルまたはビューを選択し」と書いてありますがそれがどれか分かりません。ほかのサイトで「sys.tables」を読み込んでいるサイトがありましたがそれでは全く違ったテーブルが読み込まれました。

Windows 10 Home 1909、Microsoft Access 2019 です。どなたかAccessからSQLServerにリンクテーブルで接続する方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: こちらの説明が該当しそうですが。[わかりやすく解説！AccessでSQLserverのリンクテーブルを追加する方法](https://enoxproduction.com/access-link-table/)

Comment: 素早いおお返事ありがとうございます。そちらのサイトは検索上位に出てきますので拝見いたしました。「sys.tables」を読み込んだ後が分かりませんでした。

Comment: 紹介した記事の最初の方に「リンクテーブルに設定したいデータベースの情報やテーブルの情報などが必要になりますので、設定前に確認しておいてください。」とあります。あなたが参考にした記事を書いた人の使っているSQLServerと同じ構成・設定のSQLServerに接続したので無ければ同じテーブルにはならないでしょう。あなたが接続したSQLServer上での「リンクテーブルに設定したいデータベースの情報やテーブルの情報」は確認されていますでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、見落としていた様です。後日確認したいと思います。ありがとうございます！

Comment: ご呈示のサイトをもう一度拝見して確認したのですが、「リンクテーブルに設定したいデータベースの情報やテーブルの情報」が何に当たるのかが分かりません。何を確認したらいいのでしょう？

Comment: 例えば古い版数向け記事のようですがこのページ [Access.mdb(accdb)からSQL Serverのテーブルにリンクする方法](http://www.dcns.ne.jp/~sk7n2jch/Acc01.html) の最後の図にあるような情報ではありませんか？ 他に図は無いですが、こんな記事が参考になるかも。[AccessリンクテーブルをVBAで行う(SQLServer編)](https://t-yumi.jp/gengo/access/201909111426211440.html), [SQLServer のリンクテーブルをAccess側で作成](http://tibirobo.jpn.org/?p=1811), [クライアントＰＣのAccessからSQL Serverへの接続の方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/104192)